# mailto links not opening after upgrade to Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, email, thunderbird, mail

Ever since upgrading from Kubuntu 21.04 to 21.10, mailto links in both Firefox and Chromium don't work anymore. No error message when I click them, just nothing happens.

Thunderbird is set as the default email application in system settings. I checked in Firefox and Thunderbird is set as the handler for mailto. Switching to the other options (Gmail and Yahoo!) doesn't work either. Not sure where to check the mailto handler in Chrome/Chromium, but it seems like it's a system problem rather than browser-specific.

Not sure if it's related, but when I run `xdg-email` I get `thunderbird.desktop: not found`. Thunderbird is however installed and the desktop file is where all the others are in `/usr/share/applications` with `644` permissions.

Also not sure if it's related, but if I run `kde-open5 whoever@wherever.com` it opens a new Thunderbird compose window.

Any idea what the issue might be here?